# How to use mongoexport in count?

Tags: mongodb, export

I want to get the count of all rows in a single collection into an output file. What is the correct way of doing this

Here is what I did but I am encountering an error.

```
mongoexport --host 10.1.0.1:27017 --db proddb --collection  UserColl --query "{db.getCollection('UserColl').count()}" --type=csv --out=output.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Using mongoexport here is a working example of what I did to get the count without having double expensive calls. Hope it helps you. All this really does is save the command output to a file and then you can query the file for a specific string (sed). In this case the number of records the command exported. FYI, this hits a Mongo 6.0.6 db. Also not sure if you are using bash or not but....

```
##############################################################################################
##### Lets make sure that the last run (2 days ago) happened and there is a file for it. #####
##############################################################################################
#!/bin/bash

_mongoExportToFolder=/mnt/backups/mongodb/k8s/mongoexport/
_mongoDBToBpk=mdc
_mongoDBCollectionToBpk=logs
_logsdir=/mnt/backup/scripts/logs/
_mongoMIexportLogFile=${_logsdir}MongoExportDaily_MdcLogs_K8s_CRON.log
_mongo_host=xxx.xx.x.xx
_mongo_port=27017
_mongo_search_starttime="T00:00:00.000Z"
_mongo_search_endtime="T23:59:59.000Z"

_twoDaysAgoDate=$(date -d "2 days ago" +"%Y-%m-%d")
_twoDaysAgoDateStart="${_twoDaysAgoDate}${_mongo_search_starttime}"
_twoDaysAgoDateEnd="${_twoDaysAgoDate}${_mongo_search_endtime}"
_twoDaysAgoQuery="{\"entrytimestamp\":{\"\$gte\":{\"\$date\":\"${_twoDaysAgoDateStart}\"},\"\$lte\":{\"\$date\":\"${_twoDaysAgoDateEnd}\"}}}"
_twoDaysAgoFilename="${_mongoExportToFolder}mdc_logs_${_twoDaysAgoDate}.json"
_twoDaysAgoCountLogFilename="/tmp/twoDaysAgoDateCount.out"

if [[ ! -f "${_twoDaysAgoFilename}" ]]; then
    echo "$(date +"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S") MongoExport _twoDaysAgoQuery: $_twoDaysAgoQuery" >> $_mongoMIexportLogFile
    echo "$(date +"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S") MongoExport twoDaysAgo Filename: $_twoDaysAgoFilename" >> $_mongoMIexportLogFile
    echo "$(date +"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S") ${_twoDaysAgoFilename} DOES NOT EXIST WILL RUN NOW." >> $_mongoMIexportLogFile

    echo ""
    if [[ -f ${_twoDaysAgoCountLogFilename} ]]; then
      rm ${_twoDaysAgoCountLogFilename}
    fi

    mongoexport --db=${_mongoDBToBpk} -c=${_mongoDBCollectionToBpk} -q="${_twoDaysAgoQuery}" mongodb://${_mongo_host}:${_mongo_port}/${_mongoDBToBpk} -o ${_twoDaysAgoFilename} 1>${_twoDaysAgoCountLogFilename} 2>&1

    while read -r CURRENT_LINE
      do
      _count=$( echo "$CURRENT_LINE" | sed -En "s/.*exported\s([0-9]{1,55})\srecords.*/\1/p" )
    done < "${_twoDaysAgoCountLogFilename}"

    if [[ -z $_count ]]; then
      echo "$(date +"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S") Error occured. twoDaysAgoCountLogFilename NO records to export."
    else
      echo "$(date +"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S") MongoExport _twoDaysAgoQuery: RAN the export. Exported ${_count} records." >> $_mongoMIexportLogFile
    fi

else
    echo "$(date +"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S") MongoExport twoDaysAgo Filename: $_twoDaysAgoFilename EXISTS NO ACTION REQUIRED" >> $_mongoMIexportLogFile
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample.js file like the sample below:

```
db=db.getSiblingDB('DbName');

printjson( db.getCollection('CollectionName').find().count() );
```

then I run this script below on cmd:

```
mongo --host IP:PORT --username username --password password --authenticationDatabase admin --quiet sample.js > sample.csv
```